# Stripe doesn't support in order to create multiple line items on an invoice using API call

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I'm creating an invoice using Stripe's API call. Based on [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create), there is no amount parameters for generated invoice and I always get zero in amount_due.

Another issue is I want to add line items in generate invoice, but there is no places to add line items for generated invoice.

Here is my code;

```
$params = [
      'customer' => $stripeCustomer['stripeCustomerId'],
      'auto_advance' => true,
      'collection_method' => 'charge_automatically',
      'currency' => Str::lower($record['CurrencyCode']),
      'metadata' => $metaData,
    ];

$stripeInvoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create($params);
```

And stripe return object is here;

```
{
  "id": "in_1M6otQLHPCwYGWEgSQraCHVf",
  "object": "invoice",
  "account_country": "SG",
  "account_name": "Demo",
  "account_tax_ids": null,
  "amount_due": 0,
  "amount_paid": 0,
  "amount_remaining": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "attempt_count": 0,
  "attempted": false,
  "auto_advance": true,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": false,
    "status": null
  },
  "billing_reason": "manual",
  "charge": null,
  "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
  "created": 1669094376,
  "currency": "sgd",
  "custom_fields": null,
  "customer": "cus_MqVqznCTTb78Ct",
  "customer_address": {
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "line1": "",
    "line2": "",
    "postal_code": "",
    "state": ""
  },
  "customer_email": "john.doe@doe.com",
  "customer_name": "John Doe",
  "customer_phone": null,
  "customer_shipping": null,
  "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
  "customer_tax_ids": [
  ],
  "default_payment_method": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "default_tax_rates": [
  ],
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "discounts": [
  ],
  "due_date": null,
  "ending_balance": null,
  "footer": null,
  "from_invoice": null,
  "hosted_invoice_url": null,
  "invoice_pdf": null,
  "last_finalization_error": null,
  "latest_revision": null,
  "lines": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
    "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1M6otQLHPCwYGWEgSQraCHVf/lines"
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
    "invoiceNumber": "INV-0005",
    "invoiceId": "fcca9507-411d-4087-b940-03251402beab"
  },
  "next_payment_attempt": 1669097976,
  "number": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "paid": false,
  "paid_out_of_band": false,
  "payment_intent": null,
  "payment_settings": {
    "default_mandate": null,
    "payment_method_options": null,
    "payment_method_types": null
  },
  "period_end": 1669094376,
  "period_start": 1669094376,
  "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
  "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
  "quote": null,
  "receipt_number": null,
  "rendering_options": null,
  "starting_balance": 0,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "status": "draft",
  "status_transitions": {
    "finalized_at": null,
    "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
    "paid_at": null,
    "voided_at": null
  },
  "subscription": null,
  "subtotal": 0,
  "subtotal_excluding_tax": 0,
  "tax": null,
  "test_clock": null,
  "total": 0,
  "total_discount_amounts": [
  ],
  "total_excluding_tax": 0,
  "total_tax_amounts": [
  ],
  "transfer_data": null,
  "webhooks_delivered_at": 1669094376
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Invoices Create API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create) always creates an empty invoice first, then use [Invoice Items Create API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create) to add line items to the invoice later.

You may refer to the doc here for the step-by-step integration: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration